Leveraging symmetry in square matrix problems
Consider the problem of filling in a square matrix with non-negative integers subject to some constraints, and assume the problem has all the symmetries of the square, i.e. for any putative solution, any rotated or reflected version of it is also a solution.
My question is: what general criterion/constraint could I impose on the solution/search space in order to only pick one solution (one matrix) out of any one symmetry class?  In other words, how to characterise/find solutions up to symmetry?
To be clear, I am hoping for some constraint directly on the elements of any given matrix, i.e. a criterion to check that a given matrix is "canonical" by just inspecting its elements.
(E.g. I often cut the solution space in half by imposing that the top-left corner is less than the top-right corner, but that is far from recovering all square symmetries, and it is anyway not general, as it only works if all elements in a row are distinct. -- Indeed, I am open to the possibility that there is no direct way, i.e. by just constraints between a matrix elements, not in general.)

Here is a simple concrete example for clarity:
Problem: fill a 2x2 matrix with numbers 0 and 1 so that no two adjacent numbers (horizontally or vertically) are equal.
We find 2 solutions:
10       01
01  and  10

But they are the same solution up to symmetry.
And here, quite simply (we can see it by inspection), we can prune the solution/search space by just imposing the constraint that the top-left element is less than the top-right element: in symbols, denoting square elements by $M_{i,j}$ with $i,j$ 1-based, that is $M_{1,1} \lt M_{1,2}$.
But of course that only works in this very simple problem instance, I am rather looking for a constraint that works with square matrices of any size for all problem instances, just provided the problem is fully square-symmetric.
A more substantial motivating example is this Puzzling question:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/128939

Given an order relation $\le$ on the solutions, you could require $solution \le R(solution)$ for each member $R$ of the symmetry group other than the identity.

"I have a sudoku-like square problem": please include a presentation of the problem, and your solution attempts of the problem, directly in your posted question.

I am also playing with the idea of a unique number associated to each matrix such that all matrices of the same symmetry class have the same number, though that is not in the direction of canonicity as a constraint over a matrix elements, which is what I need for constraint programming...

[This is partial and tentative, indeed just an attempt at narrowing things down up to a couple of pseudo-working hypotheses: feedback and other answers are most welcome. -- I will be cleaning this up along the way as I can.]
In full generality, I think the question could be states as:

Given any equivalence relation $\equiv$ on $\mathbb{S}_n$,
where $\mathbb{S}_n$ is the space of all $n\!\times\!n$
matrices over $\mathbb{N}$, find a characterisation
of canonical under $\equiv$, i.e. a function
$[\cdot]_\equiv : \mathbb{S}_n \to \mathbb{S}_n$
such that $[x]_\equiv$ is a canonical representative
of the class of $x$ under $\equiv$.

That provided, the constraint in the original question can be
expressed as $x = [x]_\equiv$.
But, given arbitrary $\equiv$, how to find a "characterisation
of canonical"?  A simple one?  In general??

I cannot think of a $[\cdot]$ whose definition does not depend
on the details of $\equiv$, i.e. concretely on what classes
$\equiv$ induces and what concrete relationship there is between
elements of a class.  And I can hardly think of a $[\cdot]$ that
needn't check in the worst case all possible subsets of entries
of a matrix to determine what the corresponding canonical
representation is...
Or, maybe, along a quite different line, the answer is: as long as
$\equiv$ is reflected by a (given) computable function...?!

Work in progress...
